# Translates of sets: Is it true that v + conv(A) = conv(v + A)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

If A is a subset of R^n, and v is an element of R^n, then we define the translate of a set to be: v + A = (v + x : x is an element of A)

Is it necessarily true that v + conv(A) = conv(v + A)?

Since v is a single element of A, then that implies v = conv(v).

Based on this, we have conv(v) + conv(A) = conv(v + A), is this true, and is there a formula or mechanism that can be used to prove this statement?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried it directly from the definition?

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda_k \ge 0$ and $\sum_k \lambda_k = 1$, then
$v + \sum_k \lambda_k a_k = \sum_k \lambda_k (v + a_k)$ from which the result follows.

Here is another way that relies on the following facts:
(i) $\operatorname{co} B$ is the smallest convex set containing $B$.
(ii) If $L$ is linear and $C$ is convex, then $L(C)$ is convex.
(iii) If $A,B$ are convex, then so is $A \times B$.

Then we see that for any $p$, $\{p\} + \operatorname{co} A $ is convex since
$\{p\} \times \operatorname{co} A$ is convex and the map $(x,y) \to x+y$ is linear. In particular, the translates of a convex set by any $p$ are convex.

Since $\{v\} +  A  \subset \{v\} + \operatorname{co} A $ and the right hand
side is convex, we see that
$\operatorname{co} ( \{v\} +  A  ) \subset \{v\} + \operatorname{co} A $.

Now note that $A \subset (\{v\} +A ) + \{-v\} \subset \operatorname{co} ( \{v\} +  A  ) + \{-v\}$, and since the right hand side is convex, we have
$ \operatorname{co} A \subset \operatorname{co} ( \{v\} +  A  ) + \{-v\}$.

Since $\{v \}$ is a singleton, we can add to both sides to get
$\{v \} + \operatorname{co} A \subset \operatorname{co} ( \{v\} +  A  )$.